# Alter field values via module

Tags: 7, entities, cron

How can I update field values of all nodes via module?

I have a `hook_cron` function inside `MYMODULE.module` that updates `field_popularity_score` field of all nodes, of a particular type, so that I can use Views to sort the nodes by `field_popularity_score`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal 7, you should use a [queue](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7) for such type of operations. In short, what happens is the following:

- An item is added to the queue
- An item in the queue is processed, and removed

In the case of cron tasks, there is a hook ([hook_cron_queue_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7)) that tells Drupal which queues need to be handled when [drupal_cron_run()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7) is executed, and which function handles the items contained in the queue.

```
function mymodule_cron_queue_info() {
  $queues['mymodule_update_node_popularity'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'mymodule_update_node_popularity', 
    'time' => 20,
  );

  return $queues;
}
```

For how to populate that queue, I see two possible cases:

- The field is updated for every node that is updated
- The field is updated for every node, once
- The field is updated for every node that is created, or updated

In all the cases, the following function should be used, together the hook I previously shown.

```
function mymodule_update_node_popularity($nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);

  // Calculate the new score for the node.

  $node->field_popularity_score[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $new_value;
  // Replace the previous line with the following one, if the value should be different for each language.
  // $node->field_popularity_score[field_language('node', $node, 'field_popularity_score')][0]['value'] = $new_value;

  node_save($node);
}
```

The parameter received from the worker callback (in this case, `mymodule_update_node_popularity()`) is the one that is passed to [$queue->createItem()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/function/DrupalQueueInterface%3a%3acreateItem/7).

In the first case, I would implement the following code.

```
function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'content type to handle') {
    $queue = DrupalQueue::get('mymodule_update_node_popularity');
    $queue->createItem($node->nid);
  }
}
```

In the second case, I would implement the following code.

```
function mymodule_cron() {
  $args = array(
    ':type' => 'content type to check',
    ':created' => variable_get('mymodule_last_checked', 0), 
  );
  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('mymodule_update_node_popularity');

  $nodes_result = db_query('SELECT nid, created FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND created >= :created ORDER BY created ASC', $args);
  foreach ($nodes_result as $node) {
    $queue->createItem($node->nid);
    variable_set('mymodule_last_checked', $node->created);
  }
}
```

The reason I am not using `"SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type"` as query is that such query would cause `mymodule_cron()` to always add the same nodes to the queue (except for those nodes that have been deleted). `mymodule_cron()` needs a way to filter out the nodes that have been already handled, and the query I wrote is a way to achieve that.
The value passed to `$queue->createItem()` can also be an array, or an object, and that value would be passed to the worker callback.

In the third case, I would use the following code.

```
function mymodule_cron() {
  $args = array(
    ':type' => 'content type to check',
    ':changed' => variable_get('mymodule_last_checked', 0), 
  );
  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('mymodule_update_node_popularity');

  $nodes_result = db_query('SELECT nid, changed FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND changed >= :changed ORDER BY changed ASC', $args);
  foreach ($nodes_result as $node) {
    $queue->createItem($node->nid);
    variable_set('mymodule_last_checked', $node->changed);
  }
}
```

This code works because, when a node is first created, both `$node->created`, and `$node->changed` are set to the same value.

In the first case, when you need to update the field value when the node is updated, you could implement [hook_field_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7), instead of using a Drupal queue.

Comment: Hi, I went with the second case. Can you clarify what's happening in the second case? What is $queue = DrupalQueue.... and why does the query request node.created value and limited to 10? Also, where does it define the $nid variable inside node_load($nid). Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see now; in the second case - The field is updated for every node, once, only if the node has been updated since the last cron. I thought that it processed all nodes on every cron, regardless of node update status. I'm excited to try this out.

Comment: `hook_cron()` can be interrupted before it handles all the nodes because PHP took too much time to execute it; imagine what would happen in a site with 500 nodes. In that case, it needs a way to avoid starting again from the nodes already handled, when there are nodes still to handle.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to add some sort of queuing mechanism so that your cron run doesn't time out, but this would be one way:

```
// Get the nids
$args = array(':type' => 'type');
$nids = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type', $args)->fetchCol();

// Load the nodes
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

// Loop through and update each field value
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node-> field_popularity_score[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = function_to_get_value();

  // Save the node
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: Great answer also.